# Django geospatial query relating two fields of the same model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I have an `Alert` model that has `coordinates`, and `distance` as fields. I would like to make a query that pulls all alerts that are at a distance lesser than the alerts `distance` field value from given coordinates.

If this did not use GIS features, I could use F objects in Django, but F objects are apparently not supported in geospatial queries.

How to achieve such a query? 
Here is the query that I ideally would like to be able to do:

```
Alert.objects.filter(coordinates__distance_lte=(coordinates, F("distance")))
```

I am running GeoDjango over Postgis.

Here is the relevant part of the Alert Model:

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    coordinates = models.PointField()
    distance = models.IntegerField()
```

Here is the SQL that I would like to see generated:

```
select * from alert where ST_Distance_Sphere(coordinates, 'POINT(3 50)') < distance;
```

Obviously, I have a solution by doing a raw query, but I was curious to see if this is doable directly through the ORM.

Comment: it might help to share the Alert model.

Comment: Can you use ST_DWithin, something like, Alert.objects.filter(coordinates__dwithin=(pnt, 1000))

Comment: The problem is that I would like the value 1000 to not be fixed, but dependent on the current row in the database.

Comment: I'm not suggesting 1000 be fixed, just that you use dwithin, which is more appropriate for the query you are trying to run. Obviously, you can substitute distance for 1000.

Comment: I do believe this is doable in Django 1.9 which wasn't available at the time you asked this question. however what's not clear to me is whether you want to do a self join on your table (the first part of the question indicates so), or you wish to compare a against a fixed point (the raw query indicates that)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution ?